# Java: handle time-expressions

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I am using a Java backend to store different events. Up to now Date is used to store date and time specific information. It would be nice to allow "more natural" time definitions like "afternoon", "morning" or "soon".

Are there any best practices to handle these flexible/not well specified but often used time specifiers? Are there some libraries to transform them into Date objects (and vice versa)?

Comment: You have to define what you mean by your time definitions.  For instance, afternoon is somewhere between 1 pm and 4 pm; morning is somewhere between 8 am and 11 am; and soon is within the next 3 hours.  Once you've defined your words, you can write the conversions yourself.

Comment: ok, this is obvious. But are there any standards or libraries? I think this is a quite common task!

Comment: No, it's not so obvious.  One application needs to define morning as 4 am to 7 am, while another application (for teenagers) needs to define morning as 1 pm to 4 pm.  It's application dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing that by hand. Just create a wrapper class and make an enum with values AfterNoon, Morning, ... And provide a constructor that takes a Date object and code the logic as you want.

```
Class DateWrapper {
      private Date date;
      private DayTime dayTime;

      public DateWrapper (Date date){
         ...
       }


       public enum DayTime {
         Morning, AfterNoon, ...;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the time that you want to set for those things, but here's an example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class currentTime
{  public static void main(String[] args)
   {  currentTime a_SmartHello=new currentTime();
      GregorianCalendar todaysDate=new GregorianCalendar();
      int hour,
      minute,
      hour_of_day,
      am_pm;

      hour=todaysDate.get(Calendar.HOUR);
      hour_of_day=todaysDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      minute=todaysDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      am_pm=todaysDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

      a_SmartHello.sayTime(hour,minute,am_pm);

      if (hour_of_day<12)
      {  a_SmartHello.sayGoodMorning();
      }
      if (hour_of_day>11 && hour_of_day<17)
      {  a_SmartHello.sayGoodAfternoon();
      }
      if (hour_of_day>=17 && hour_of_day<22)
        a_SmartHello.sayGoodEvening();
      if (hour_of_day>=22)
        a_SmartHello.sayGoodNight();
    }

    private void sayGoodMorning()
    {  System.out.println("Good Morning World!");
    }

    private void sayGoodAfternoon()
    {  System.out.println("Good Afternoon World!");
    }

    private void sayGoodEvening()
    {  System.out.println("Good Evening World!");
    }

    private void sayGoodNight()
    {  System.out.println("Good Night World! I'm going to bed!!!!");
    }

    private void sayTime(int hour, int minute, int am_pm)
    {  NumberFormat minFormat=NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
       minFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
       String am_pm_string;

       if (am_pm==0)
       {  am_pm_string="AM";
       }
       else
       { am_pm_string="PM";
       }

       System.out.println("The time is - "+hour+":"+minFormat.format(minute)+am_pm_string);
    }
}
```

From http://my.hsonline.net/~rrosetta/Java/javatutorial.htm